# Access denied Content.IE5 when copying a file in C# called by a powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell, copy

I'm trying to copy a file to my AppData Roaming folder by using the `File.Copy(string source, string dest)` command from the from the System.IO namespace.

This works well when I try it but when I call the programm from a powershell script like this:

```
$p = Start-Process  $WorkingDir\src\Installer.exe -PassThru
$p.WaitForExit()
$p.ExitCode
```

An exception is thrown by the C# program:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The access to the path "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5" has been denied.
Thanks for your help,
Sandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it:
I was using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and this is the working directory of the PowerShell!
So if you run a program from the powershell this directory is the working directory of the powershell and not the directory the program itself is detected in.

Answer (score 0):

To access system directories you need administrator privileges

to solve this you can request for admin privileges

add an Application Manifest File to your project
and Change the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` element to

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: I'm going to try this next week.
Thanks for the fast reply :)